# Custom combobox

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make combobox with filtering which looks like this

[image]

[image]

Is there any opensource solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Try the jQueryUI Autocomplete plugin with custom data and display

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data

Answer (score 0):

A simple search action for "custom dropdown" may give you some options.

For example: [jquery-image-dropdown](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown).